# Mathematica: How to apply function to a certain column of a table

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I would like to apply a function to a specific column of a table. Say to the i-th column of a (m x n) table. Actually I just want to multiply all elements in that column with a scalar, but the application of a general function would be fine as well.

It probably just needs some Map or MapAt command, maybe combined with a Transpose in order to apply to rows instead of columns - but I can't figure out the correct syntax for addressing an entire column (or row)..

Any hints would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Better question for http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example,

```
ranfunc=Function[{f,mat, n},Transpose[MapAt[f /@ # &, Transpose[mat], n]]]
```

will apply f to each element of the nth column of mat. So, for instance,

```
ranfunc[Sin[Cos[#]] &, {{1, 2, 3}, {a, b, c}, {\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma]}}, 2]
```

will apply Sin[Cos[#]]& to each element of the second column, while

```
ranfunc[s*# &, {{1, 2, 3}, {a, b, c}, {\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma]}},2]
```

will multiply each element on the second column by s

Comment: Yeah, that works. Thanks!
I was missing the nested map ( /@ ) inside the MapAt in my own attempts.
BTW: If one is just after a multiplication of, say, column 2 of 3 total, a matrix multiplication A.DiagonalMatrix[{1,s,1}] will also do the trick. But your solution is way more elegant and flexible.

Answer (score 17):

Here's a 3x3 table:

```
In[1]:= table = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}}
Out[1]= {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
In[2]:= table//TableForm
Out[2]//TableForm= 1   2   3
                   4   5   6
                   7   8   9
```

Column 2 is `table[[All, 2]]`:

```
In[3]:= table[[All, 2]]
Out[3]= {2, 5, 8}
```

So it's a simple matter to modify only that column:

```
In[4]:= table[[All, 2]] = 10 * table[[All, 2]]
Out[4]= {20, 50, 80}
In[5]:= table//TableForm
Out[5]//TableForm= 1   20   3
                   4   50   6
                   7   80   9
```

Comment: Another elegant way to do it is like the cumulative functions in C: 
table[[All, 2]] *= 10

Answer (score 7):

One versatile approach is to use ReplacePart

For example, to apply f to column 3 of mat:

```
(mat = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {4, 4}]) // MatrixForm

(newmat = ReplacePart[#, 3 -> f  @#[[3]] ] & /@ mat) // MatrixForm
```

The following multiplies each entry by 10:

```
(newmat2 = ReplacePart[#, 3 -> 10 #[[3]] ] & /@ mat) // MatrixForm
```

However, a 'quick' way to do this it as follows:

```
mat[[All, 3 ]] *= 10
```

(Unlike the first method, all entries in column 3 of mat are now modified. It is not clear whether you want to modify the existing table, or to create a new table with modifications, leaving the original intact)

Comment: +1, I definitely like the use of `ReplacePart` for this over the `MapAt` implementation as that requires the use of Transpose to be effective.

Answer (score 6):

MapAt function accepts the following Part specification:

```
MapAt[f, mat, {All, 3}]
```

to apply 'f' to column 3 of your matrix.

Answer (score 4):

Another compact solution I found is using Map and MapAt:

Here is an example Matrix:

```
mat={{3,4,5},{4,7,5},{2,6,7},{3,6,9}}
```

Now apply the function f to the second column:

```
n=2;
Map[MapAt[f,#,n]&,mat]
```

The result is then:

```
{{3,f[4],5},{4,f[7],5},{2,f[6],7},{3,f[6],9}}
```

Comment: Elegant, readable, and works with in-line code, e.g., when manipulating a list before plotting it, like multiplying the x-column by two: ListPlot[Map[MapAt[Function[x, 2 x], #, 1] &, list]]

Comment: Thanks to you I discovered `MapAt`! However, the `Map` wrapper is not even needed, you could directly write `MapAt[f,mat,{All,2}]`.