# Excel: sum of a column, but apply a function to each cell before sum

Tags: excel

I have a basic excel spreadsheet like this:

```
A           B           C          D       etc..
10%         219.10      34.2       6.4     etc..
6%          45.10       36.2       7.4     etc..
4%          419.10      54.2       9.4     etc..
Totals:     [SUM]       [SUM]      [SUM]   ( -- update - need totals here -- )
```

I would like to sum all the values in column B, C and D. Each cell value needs to be multiplied by the % in column A before doing the sum()

I could manually create a new column to contain the % calculation, and sum that column up, but I'm hoping to do it without the additional column.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570652/mathematica-how-to-apply-function-to-a-certain-column-of-a-table) which I think is on the right track but am a little lost at implementing it.

(planning to write this calculation to an excel spreadsheet created from a php script based on values in a simple mysql database)

Comment: (updated) - my bad, the "etc.." threw some people off. Would like the sums underneath each column.

Comment: B5 would contain: =SUMPRODUCT(B2:B4, A2:A4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### EDIT

For the updated question, all you need is (in B5)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B4 * $A2:$A4)
```

Copy to the right

---

For E2, use

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:D2 * $A2)
```

This means B2*A2 + C2*A2 + D2*A2.

But, **did you know** that mathematically speaking, it is the same as

```
  B2*A2 + C2*A2 + D2*A2
= A2 * (B2+C2+D2)
```

Which is just this below?

```
=A2*SUM(B2:D2)
```

Looking at your etc, if you need to expand it rightwards, just keep column A locked in SUMPRODUCT, or use the SUM.  Example below for up to J

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:J2 * $A2)
=A2*SUM(B2:J2)
```

And copy down.

Comment: +1, you don't need any fancy-schmancy Excel wizardry for this. Just use that last formula.

Comment: this is a special case of array formulas.  From O2K11: Using arrays provides a more general solution for doing operations similar to SUMPRODUCT. For example, you can calculate the sum of the squares of the elements in A2:B4 by using the formula =SUM(A2:B4^2) and pressing ⌘+RETURN.

Comment: Thanks, SUMPRODUCT is what I was after.

Comment: @dtbaker, @cyberwiki - Perhaps I'm missing something, but why would anything other than the last formula be needed in this trivial case (although I would make A2 an absolute reference)? Without any rounding or other operations, SUMPRODUCT and the last formula should be equal due to the distributive property.

Answer (score 0):

Use array formulas e.g. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx

These are generally expressed by the control-shift-enter idiom

Comment: So the sum of B * A would be written as `{=A2:A4*B2:B4}`  (if you use control-shift-enter to force it to evaluate as an array, the curly braces will show up)

Comment: @cyberkiwi You can run the calculation the other way around, but given that the etc is written to the right, I presumed that the sum Ai*Bi was more meaningful than A * (B + C + D)

Comment: exactly why you would put a total row :)